# slam_toolbox with IntelRealsense publishing empty /map topic

Tags: ros2, slam, odometry, realsense-camera, map-to-odom

I will preface that I am fairly new to ROS. I have been trying to acheive SLAM with slam_toolbox using my IntelRealsense D455 depth camera in Ros2 Humble, but /map topic output is empty, which I beleive stems from the fact that either my camera or /tf topic is failing to publish an /odom topic, which slam_toolbox expects.

This camera does have an internal IMU and I can confirm that the /camera/imu topic is being published. **How can I "convert" this /imu topic to an /odom topic?** (Is this even the right approach?)

I have found little documentation for using slam_toolbox with an intelRealsense and Ros2. The documentation that does exist (as in this post: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/issues/2387) points to using depthimage_to_laserscan to convert the camera's depth map to a /scan topic. My understanding is that slam_toolbox expects a /scan, /odom, and /tf topic, and since my /scan and /tf topics appear to be working below, I reason that the issue is to do with the lack of an /odom topic.

ros2 topic list returns:

```
    /camera/accel/imu_info
    /camera/accel/metadata
    /camera/accel/sample
    /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/camera_info
    /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw
    /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw/compressed
    /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw/compressedDepth
    /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw/theora
    /camera/color/camera_info
    /camera/color/image_raw
    /camera/color/image_raw/compressed
    /camera/color/image_raw/compressedDepth
    /camera/color/image_raw/theora
    /camera/color/metadata
    /camera/depth/camera_info
    /camera/depth/color/points
    /camera/depth/image_rect_raw
    /camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressed
    /camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth
    /camera/depth/image_rect_raw/theora
    /camera/depth/metadata
    /camera/extrinsics/depth_to_accel
    /camera/extrinsics/depth_to_color
    /camera/extrinsics/depth_to_depth
    /camera/extrinsics/depth_to_gyro
    /camera/gyro/imu_info
    /camera/gyro/metadata
    /camera/gyro/sample
    /camera/imu
    /clicked_point
    /clock
    /goal_pose
    /initialpose
    /map
    /map_metadata
    /map_updates
    /parameter_events
    /pose
    /rosout
    /scan
    /slam_toolbox/feedback
    /slam_toolbox/graph_visualization
    /slam_toolbox/scan_visualization
    /slam_toolbox/update
    /tf
    /tf_static`
```

Rviz says "no map received"
[image]

rqt graph:
[image]

Closer look at the TF

[image]

Thanks in advance.